# hg mercurial - how to merge in 3 way merge window in shell

Tags: python, django, mercurial, merge, tortoisehg

I have less experience with mercurial. i am having this problem:

I push everytime from my windows pc in tortoiseHG-Workbench to repo. works fine.

I pull to my server from repo with `hg pull ...`. works fine.

then it asks me to run `hg update`. i will do it. but then it says, there is something to merge in my views.py and automatically opens a 3-way merge window in shell. I am using ssh tunnel - PuTTy.

in this 3way merge window, no hg commands are available. what i always do is:

```
> views.py  #emptying the file
then i copy paste the views.py from my local pc to server and save it.
```

this works. but thru this, there will be always conflict because i am changing the same views.py in both sides. how do i solve this so that i dont have to merge everytime? i desperately need some help!

the problem is, there is no hg commands available in 3-way merge window

Comment: Are your production and development scripts different? Because if they are not, you can always do `hg update -C` which will give you the clean version of the `tip` and you'll never have to merge.

Comment: @ViktorKerKez, no, i have only one script for both dev and prod. will ``hg update -C`` take the latest ``'other'`` version which is coming from my repo?

Comment: Yes, `hg pull` and then `hg update -C` will give you the latest `other` version coming from your repo.

Comment: @Viktorkerkez, oh thats cool. thank you, you saved me from much work. you answer and i check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any differences between your production and development script that should be merged, it is safe to always do `update clean` with `update -C`. This will replace all local changes you made with the latest version that you pulled from the repository. So the workflow would be:

```
hg pull
hg update -C
```